# Postgres SQL query runs very slow when using current_date

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

We have a SQL query using a where clause to filter the data set by date. Currently the where clause in the query is set as follows -

```
WHERE date_field BETWEEN current_date - integer @interval AND current_date (where the interval is the last 90 days)
```

This query has suddenly started to slow down for the past couple of days. It has started to take upwards of 10 mins. If we remove the current_date from this query and hard code dates in this query it runs like it used to previously in less than 10 seconds.

Hard-coded version

```
WHERE date_field BETWEEN '03-12-2020' AND '06-12-2020'
```

This query is run against the Postgres engine in Amazon Aurora. The same where clause is used in other queries filter against the same field which are not impacted by this issue.

I am trying to figure out how we can determine what caused this issue suddenly and how we can resolve this?

Comment: Can you also `explain analyze` both queries and add it to the question? :)

Comment: Better yet, `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.

Comment: Your hard coded date is a timestamp without timezone, whereas current_timestamp is timestamp with timezone. Did you tried localtimestamp instead ?